# stacking methods or double methods?

Tags: python-3.x, methods

I was working on the code below in Python and I originally had it as the TOP. However, the following problem came up:" AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' ." I was thinking that after I have append it to listNum that I would then split it. One solution was to have it as the BOTTOM, where the following was used: "  inf = mainFile.read().split()  ." That looks odd and at first I thought it wouldn't work, but turns out it was the solution to the problem I was facing. In what instances is double stacking permitted as I think that its not commonly observed? Further, is there a name or what is it called for this type of syntax so I can do more research on it.

```
def computes(textFile):
    listNum = list()
    with open(textFile) as mainFile:
        mainFile.read()
        for number in mainFile:
            listNum.append(int(number))
    listNum.split()
    summed = sum(listNum)
    avgNum = sum(summed)/len(listNum)
    return avgNum

def main():
    textFile = input("Enter the text file: ")
    print(computes(textFile))


main()






def computes(textFile):
    listNum = list()
    with open(textFile) as mainFile:
        inf = mainFile.read().split()
        for number in inf:
            listNum.append(int(number))
    avgNum = sum(listNum)/len(listNum)
    return avgNum

def main():
    textFile = input("Enter the text file: ")
    print(computes(textFile))  

main()
```

Content in the textfile:
45 66 88
100 22 98

Comment: Can you add a small example of the textfile you're trying to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what you are referring to is called method chaining. If it looks odd, just know that:

```
inf = mainFile.read().split()
```

is the equivalent of

```
temp = mainFile.read()
inf = temp.split()
```

Second of all, you are performing .split() on instances of two different types in your examples.

- listNum has type list, which doesn't have a split() method defined for it
- mainFile.read() returns a str instance, for which the [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method is defined